# boto3 dynamodb connect to local or remote instances

Tags: docker, amazon-dynamodb, boto3, amazon-dynamodb-local

To all,

I am a python beginner and I have a docker local docker environment of dynamoDB but I wanted to create a class that allows me to list tables or create tables for example on either my local docker dynamodb or aws dynamo db.

```
import boto3

class DDB():

    def __init__(self):
        print("Welcome to the DynamoDB py")
    
    def ddbconnect(self,env):
        self.env = env 
        if self.env == "l":
            client = boto3.client('dynamodb',endpoint_url='http://localhost:8000')
            return env
        else:
            client = boto3.client('dynamodb')
            return env
            
    def ddbcreateTable(self,tbname,pk,sk):
        
        createResponse = client.create_table(
            AttributeDefinitions=[
                {
                    'AttributeName': pk,
                    'AttributeType': 'S',
                }, 
                {
                    'AttributeName': sk,
                    'AttributeType':'N'
                }
            ], 
            KeySchema=[
                {
                    'AttributeName': pk,
                    'KeyType':'HASH'
                },
                {
                    'AttributeName': sk,
                    'KeyType':'RANGE'
                },
            ],
            BillingMode = 'PAY_PER_REQUEST',
            TableName=tbname
        )

mydb=DDB()

env = input("enter L if it is a Local Dynamodb")
if env.lower() == "l":
    mydb.ddbconnect(env)
    
    while True:
        prompt = input("Choices are (C)reate or (L)ist Table or (E)xit -  L | C | E  : " )
        if prompt.lower() == "l":
        env=input()
        mydb.ddblist()
        continue
    elif prompt.lower() == "c":
        tbname=input("Enter the table name: ")
        pk=input("Enter the primary key: ")
        sk=input("Enter the sort key w/ numberic attribute: ")
        mydb.ddbcreateTable(tbname,pk,sk)
        continue
    elif prompt.lower() == "e" :
        print("Exiting")
        break
    else:
        print("Enter a valid selection")
        continue
```

I am sure there is a more efficient way of writing but this is kind of the logic

Comment: What problem are you having?  Is it producing an error in some environment?

Comment: A few things. Your indentations are wrong in your while loop. Also, if I select C to create a table, it calls the ddbcreateTable, but it never calls ddbconnect which would make the connection to DynamoDB. So there are quite a few problems you're looking at here.

Comment: I was trying to create a class of the existing code I had created.